# How to configure reverse proxy using Apache in Windows

Tags: windows, spring-boot, apache

I am trying to configure reverse proxy using Apache Tomcat 9 in Windows for my two spring boot applications which are deployed on a remote machine.

My applications consists of APIs & also swagger-ui is configured.

Not able to access the applications.

I updated the server.xml file in the conf folder.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           proxyName="yourdomain.com"
           proxyPort="80" />
```

Below this I added a new element -

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
  <Host name="yourdomain.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
    <Context path="/app1" docBase="http://app1-remote-server-ip:app1-remote-server-port/" debug="0" reloadable="true" />
    <Context path="/app2" docBase="http://app2-remote-server-ip:app2-remote-server-port/" debug="0" reloadable="true" />
  </Host>
</Engine>
```

I am using a single domain for both of my applications.

Note that there is no httpd.conf file in conf folder.

Once these updates were saved, I restarted the Apache Tomcat service & tried to access my applications using the urls -
http://yourdomain.com/app1
http://yourdomain.com/app2

But was not able to access the application's API docs (swagger-ui).

Checked catalina logs as well but was not able to see any logs related to this.

Also looking at possible problems because of which I may not be able to access it -

1. Above configurations
2. Firewall or network settings
3. DNS resolution

Would be helpful if I get some concrete solution for this issue.

Edit:

Need to use Apache httpd instead of Apache Tomcat.

Comment: Note: [tag:apache] is unrelated to [tag:tomcat]. Did you configure Apache httpd as well? In that case, please add the info here as well. Otherwise remove the apache tag. Also note what [tag:apache] has to say about _configuration_ questions.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Searched a lot regarding this. Seems I was a bit confused between Apache & tomcat. Right now I am configuring Apache httpd.

Comment: The only hint that I see for Apache httpd is the word "reverse proxy", the tag and your edited "need", but the whole information that you provide above is for Tomcat. Also, note that the _configuration_ of Apache httpd is not about programming and (as the tag says) often off-topic on stackoverflow